# I get an EACESS ERROR, when I use npm run dev to run a Next js Development server

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

Whenever I try to use the command 'npm run dev' to run a next js development server, I'm getting this error (down below). I've looked all over the internet for 2 hours and can't find any solution that's applicable to minds.

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1293:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1358:12)
at doListen (node:net:1496:7)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '0.0.0.0',
port: 3000
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jaydev\Desktop\nexttest\testproject
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c next dev

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jaydev\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-05-23T23_10_33_697Z-debug.log

Any solutions are highly appreciated

Comment: See if anything is already listening on port 3000 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows and either kill the task or configure either your app or the current listener to another port

Comment: Yeah, it shows that something is listening on port 3000, how do I kill the task?

Comment: nvm I figured it out, thank you so much for your help